# json result display first value

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have found several posts similar to this topic but nothing I have tried has actually worked. My question is simple and should be easy to answer. My return json object will have one key and one value. For my code below, the alert shows "[{"DISCOUNT":1}]" and all I am trying to do is parse out the "1" and display it. Ultimately, I want to plug that value into a variable and use for multiplication, but I can't even get the darn number to display by itself. My code is below:

```
function codeMatchTest() {
if ($('#dbReturnString').val() == '') {
    alert("Please enter a discount code.");
} else {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PROMO.svc/MatchCode",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ codeInput: $('#dbReturnString').val().toLowerCase() }),
    success: function (json) {
        alert(json.d);
        /*alert (json.d.discount); // getting "undefined"
        $.each(json.d, function (key, value) {
             var discount = value; 
        });
        alert("Success: " + discount); //getting "undefined" */
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("There was an error with your request.");
    }
});
}
```

}

I have found no good references on how to actually use the data in a json object. My json object will only consist of a single key and value and I will only ever need to use the value.

Also, I have tried several iteration using $.each and none work. Based on the jquery documentation, it should be very easy but I am having not luck.

Answer (score 1):

If your alert is showing `"[{"DISCOUNT":1}]"` that means you have an object within an array.

try `alert(json.d[0].DISCOUNT);`

Comment: Also I think its better practice to use console.log() instead of alert()

Comment: It is better practice but I am going to be using an alert in my program so I just started testing with alerts. As for the suggestion above, and the other similar suggestions, I am getting "undefined" when using json.d[0].DISCOUNT or json.d[0]["DISCOUNT"]. Any idea why?

Comment: Based on the data you gave us:
alert(json.d) is "[{"DISCOUNT":1}]"
if that is true then:
var mydata = [{'DISCOUNT': 1}];
alert(mydata[0].DISCOUNT); works fine

Answer (score 1):

JSON parsed objects are case sensivetive, plus its seems that json.d contains a string (wich seems to be in json) rather than an object. Try:

> var discount = JSON.parse(json.d);
>   discount = discount[0].DISCOUNT;

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This seems to be the lone working solution and should set me up for my other needs.

Comment: Your data arrives at the callback function as json...you shouldn't need to re-parse it.

Comment: frodopwns - that is exactly what I though but I tried without the parse statement above and "undefined" was returned. COnfusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(json) {
    alert(json.d[0]["DISCOUNT"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First comment on your code, you are reinventing what jQuery does.

```
data: JSON.stringify({ codeInput: $('#dbReturnString').val().toLowerCase() }),
```

It should just be

```
data: { codeInput: $('#dbReturnString').val().toLowerCase() },
```

---

Now to get the data it is simple, you are returning an array with an object in it.

Let us look at it as a regular variable and not an Ajaqx call.

```
var json = [{"DISCOUNT":1}];
```

So you got an array? How do you get the object inside of it? You reference the index. Since you said there will only be one index being returned, than use [0] to access it.

```
success: function (json) {
    alert(json[0].DISCOUNT);
```

Comment: jQuery does not convert an object into JSON. From the docs: "It is converted to a query string, if not already a string."

Answer (score 0):

To access the first item from the `json` you may use

```
alert(json.d[0].DISCOUNT);
```

Because `json.d` is an array and it contains one object which is `0` index. So, `json.d[0]` will select the first item/object from the array and using `.DISCOUNT` you can access the object's property. It's also possible to access the property like

```
alert(json.d[0]["DISCOUNT"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

You can use JSON.parse(json.d) / json.d

`var data = json.d; 
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {

alert(data[i].fieldname);
}`